# Having issues with displaying data from a json file in a embed

Tags: python, json, database, discord.py, pycord

I have been trying to show the data from my json file inside of a embed. However, I can't seem to find a way to display it and needed some help finding out how.
Here is the json file data:

```json
{
    "Slims Mod Bot": {
        "Felix\u2122": 2,
        "DustinFoes": 16,
        "Slim Beatbox": 26,
   },
```

In other words, I don't know how to show this data in a embed neatly, without all the symbols.

Here is the code that sends the data and counts the messages:

```py
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):

    if not message.author.bot: 
        with open('message_count.json','r') as f:
            global message_count
            message_count = json.load(f)
            if message.guild.name not in message_count:
                message_count[message.guild.name] = {}
        try:
                message_count[message.guild.name][message.author.name] += 1
        except KeyError:
                message_count[message.guild.name][message.author.name] = 1
        with open('message_count.json','w') as f:
                json.dump(message_count,f,indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is having the same **problem** my friend and his team found a answer:

```
@bot.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    with open('messages.json') as file:
         data = json.load(file)
    for key, value in data["Slims Mod Bot"].items():
        embed = discord.Embed(
         title="Leadboard",
         description="Test",
         color=0xFF000
        )
        embed.add_field(name = key, value = value)
        await ctx.respond(embed=embed)
```

**Please notice the difference between the first and second set of code**

```
@bot.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
         title="Leadboard",
         description="Test",
         color=0xFF000
        )
    with open('messages.json') as file:
         data = json.load(file)
    for key, value in data["Slims Mod Bot"].items():
        try:
             embed.add_field(name = key, value = value)
        except: return
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed)
```

**Instead** of "embed = discord.Embed" being below the "json.load(file)", it should be above. **However,** The embed fields **should** still be **below** the "json.load(file)"
If we **don't** do this it will cause bot to send the embed over and over again essentially making **unwanted spam** which is **against ToS**, Hope this helps!